# have p.p vs past tense

Tags: grammar, connotations

I know similar questions were asked by many others before but I am still not sure.

> They are already getting what they wanted
>
> They are already getting what they have wanted

If I understood right, the first sentence

> They are already getting what they wanted

means they are getting what they wanted in the past 
(but it is not sure they want it now)

and the second sentence

> They are already getting what they have wanted

means they are getting what they wanted and what they still want.
(and contexts should provide dates or time from when they wanted, whereas past tense doesn't require them?)

Am I understanding it correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> They are already getting what they wanted.

It's ambiguous if they still want the thing or not—although I'd say it's more likely than not. All we know from this sentence itself is that they did want it at some point in the past.

In an idiomatic sense, without the use of *already*, this can also be used in the context of *be careful what you wish for*: they're getting (exactly) what they wanted / wished for.

---

> They are already getting what they **have** wanted.

This is actually ungrammatical. There are two variations that you could use instead:

> They are already getting what they **had** wanted.
>   They are already getting what they **have been wanting**.

The normal interpretation of **had** is that the desire is no longer present. While it's still possible for it to mean the desire persists, it would not be normal.

Meanwhile, the common interpretation of **have been wanting** is that the desire continues into the present. However, it could still be interpreted the other way without much difficulty if further clarification is lacking.

Comment: Oh wow thank you for your reply. This definitely helps!